# Expendable complex types inside complex types in any collection (Property grid)

Tags: c#, devexpress

Hello I want to have a expandable collection of complex types which are inside of other complex type. 
How I want to do this:

```
 private static void SetExpandableAttrForType(Type type)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props.Where(x =>!x.PropertyType.IsSimpleType()&& x.CanWrite))
        {
            SetExpandableAttrForType(prop.PropertyType);
        }
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(type, new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof (ExpandableObjectConverter)));
    }
```

and then

```
  SetExpandableAttrForType(arrayInstance.GetType().GetElementType());
```

Test model:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class2 Class2Inclass1 { get; set; }
    public Class2[] Class2Array { get; set; }
}


public class Class2
{
    public Class3 Class3Inclass2 { get; set; }
    public string Class2String { get; set; }
    public string Class2String2 { get; set; }
}


public class Class3
{
    public Class4 Class4Inclass3 { get; set; }
    public string Class3String { get; set; }
    public int Class3Int { get; set; }
}

public class Class4
{
    public int Class4Int { get; set; }
    public DateTime Class4Datetime { get; set; }
}
```

It works fine for types but not for collection of types.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about programming is this, when u tell somebody about the problem, often you start to look at it from another angle. The problem was that I need instance of this nested complex type. CellValueChanged event give me type and then I just need to create instance of it.

```
   private void propertyGridControl1_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        var changedObject = e.Value;
        if (changedObject != null)
        {
            if (changedObject.GetType().IsArray || changedObject.GetType().IsGenericList())
            {
                var collectionItems = changedObject as IEnumerable;
                if (collectionItems != null)
                    foreach (var item in collectionItems)
                    {
                        SetValueOfCollectionComplexObject(item);
                    }
            }
        }
    }


public void SetValueOfCollectionComplexObject(object item)
{
        var complexProps = item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => !x.PropertyType.IsSimpleType());
        foreach (var prop in complexProps)
        {
            if (prop.GetValue(item) == null)
            {
                prop.SetValue(item, Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType));
                SetValueOfCollectionComplexObject(prop.GetValue(item));
            }
        }
    }
```